# Storing a geocoded address with js and php in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that there are a lot of question with the same topic, but I can not make them work in my code, because i need to do it in a different way...
I have an html form to insert the information in the db, the code is:

```
<form name="form1" action="insert.php" method="post">
    <input id="street" name="street" type="textbox" placeholder="street" maxlength="20" />
    <input id="number" name="number" type="textbox" placeholder="number" maxlength="5" />
    <input id="name" name="name" type="textbox" placeholder="Name" maxlength="40" /></div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" ></input>
</form>
```

And the "insert.php" file which is:

```
<?php
    @$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","User","Pass","DB");
        if(!$link){
        die ("Error n°".mysqli_connect_errno().": ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }   
    $sql = "INSERT INTO markers (Street, Number, Name)
            VALUES ('{$_POST['street']}','{$_POST['number']}','{$_POST['name']}')";

    $rs = mysqli_query ($link, $sqql);
    if (!$rs){
        die('Error n°'.mysqli_errno($link).": ".mysqli_error($link));
    }   
?>
```

And I usually use the simple Javascript GeoCoder Function which is:

```
<script>
function codeAddress() {
    var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
    var address = document.getElementById('street').value + ' ' + number + city;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    } else {
      alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
  });
} 
</script>
```

And the problem is that i can't find the correct way to use the geocoder in the form to store the "lat" and "lng" vars in the database. And, anyway, if i could store them then i can't make an update, because i just can change the address but not the lat and lng numbers to relocate the markers...
Here is the code of the function thats create the markers:

```
<script>
    var dblat = [];
    var dblong = [];
    var dbstreet = [];
    var dbnumber = [];
    var dbcont = 0;
    <?php   while ($v = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $latitude = $v['Latitude'];
                $longitude = $v['Longitude'];
                $street = $v['street'];
                $number = $v['number'];
    echo    "dblatitude.push($latitud);";
    echo    "dblongitude.push($longitud);";
    echo    "dbstreet.push(\"$street\");";
    echo    "dbnumber.push($number);";
    echo    "dbcont = dbcont + 1;"; 
    echo    "dblatitud.length = dbcont;";
            }; 
    ?>
function loadMarkers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < dblatitud.length; i++) {
        var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(dblatitude[i], dblongitude[i]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: latlong,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                    });
    } 
}
</script>
```

How can i insert and, if i need it, update, the lat and lng in the database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's got to be the most convoluted way to get data from PHP into javascript that I've ever seen, and the resultant javascript data structure is decidedly not the best. Instead of four separate, congruent arrays (`dblatitude`, `dblongitude` etc), why not one array containing javascript plain objects, each with properties `dblatitude`, `dblongitude` etc? The variable, `dbcont` is unnecessary as is the statement `dblatitud.length = dbcont;`. It's difficult to help when the code already written is such a mess.

Comment: without the cont var i would have some problems in others parts of the code. I had to create the js arrays to use them instead of the php ones, because i can use them more easily in other functions. But the whole code is really big, i just copy here the most important parts of the db conection. What do you recommend to "cut" the part of the arrays?

Comment: First thing to address is to do with unique IDs (UIDs or database keys). Each record in your database table must have a UID. In order to be able to update the right record, this UID must, for each record, be sent to the client so it can be sent back to the server as part of an update instruction (eg as a hidden input field in the form). Get your mind round this, and you have cracked 50% of the problem. The other 50% comprises writing client-side code that performs an ajax request including data drawn from the form (simple with jQuery), and a server-side PHP script that acts on such requests.